# Angular 9 ng2-smart table

Tags: ng2-smart-table

I am using ng2-smart-table, I am trying to do server-side pagination & sorting. I am not able to get how to do it? Once I click on page number it should go to the backend. What function/method/event I have to use, when clicked on page or sort it should go to the function which calls API.
Also I want to add a anchor link to one column, how to do that?
If you provide me some example that will be helpful.
Please help me with the solution. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure ServerDataSource with the names of the parameters your server uses for each purpose, after that you can deal with them in the server side.

```
this.dataSource = new ServerDataSource(this.http, {
  endPoint: environment.SERVICE + `your_route`,
  dataKey: 'Data',
  pagerPageKey: 'offset',
  pagerLimitKey: 'limit',
  filterFieldKey: 'query',
  sortFieldKey: 'sortby',
  sortDirKey: 'order',
  totalKey: 'Total',
});
```